# Where can I find the mysql slow log?

Tags: mysql, performance, slow-log

Just as the title says, where can I see it ?

Are there any config options for it ( like how many ms would determine if a query is slow or not ) ?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can find it in the default directory, depending on your install.  For instance, on my Red Hat, it's /var/log/mysql/

Query time is time, in seconds, over which it should start recording.
This can be done at startup and at runtime.

log-slow-queries = /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log

long_query_time = 1

Comment: At my site, I discovered someone has set log_slow_queries=ON. So I have a file in my datadir called ON containing the log. That was confusing...

Comment: Note that log-slow-queries is deprecated as of 5.1.29. The one to use thereafter is slow-query-log.

Comment: Also note that beginning with MySQL 5.1.21, a resolution of microseconds is supported when logging to a file.

Answer (score 31):

In MySQL :  `show global variables like '%slow%';`

Update : 
here's a link to the manual:
[link text](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_slow_query_log_file)

Comment: Can you link to the manual for a short answer like this?

Answer (score 7):

These are the pertinent options (and settings) I generally have/use in all my `my.cnf`s to log slow queries:

```
log_output=FILE
slow_query_log=1
slow_query_log_file=/var/log/mysql/mysql.slow 
long_query_time=0.001 
log-queries-not-using-indexes=0
```

Note that for [long_query_time](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_long_query_time),

> Beginning with MySQL 5.1.21 ... a resolution of
>   microseconds is supported when logging
>   to a file.

Answer (score 3):

Search your mysqld config file (usually, /etc/my.cnf)

At your shell:

```
grep slow /etc/my.cnf
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is something to consider as well :

If you use the option

```
log-output=TABLE
```

in you /etc/my.cnf file, look for the slow log to be a CSV storage engine based table located in, of all places, the mysql schema.

This affects the general log as well, once you enable it.

Comment: Can you log slow queries to table but the "normal" log into a file?

Comment: @surfmuggle Yes you can. If you put `log-output=FILE,TABLE`. that would do it !!! You must restart mysql to implement this.